# How to set up multiple choices list in Userform ComboBox code in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I am referencing excel cells to have drop down choice in my list in Userform. I would like to fix selection to few choices directly from VBA but not sure how to write list.. expression `Me.ComboBox1.List = ('CIBSE','ASHRAE')` does not work.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("ControlSetUp").Range("b25:b26").Value
'Me.ComboBox1.List = ('CIBSE','ASHRAE')
Me.ComboBox1.Value = Worksheets("ControlSetUp").Range("d15").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Me.ComboBox1.List = Array("CIBSE", "ASHRAE")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Combobox1.List = Split("CIBSE,ASHRAE", ",")
```

would also work, or even

```
Combobox1.List = Split("CIBSE ASHRAE")
```

using the default split separator which is a blank space.